# Python xml creating SubElements with multiple <br />

Tags: python, xml

I'm building some XML in Python. From a source string and I need to replace `\r` with break (`<br />`). The string may have several breaks.

I'm trying to get following results:

```
<foo><bar>Hello<br />world<br />I love you</bar></foo>
```

from the following string:

```
'Hello\rworld\rI love you.'
```

I've looked at `SubElement(<node>, 'br')` and I've looked into using CDATA.

Example:

```
from xml.etree.cElementTree import Element, SubElement, tostring                               

def add_xml_data(value):
    data = Element('foo')
    val_node = SubElement(data, 'bar')
    val_node.text = value
    val = value.strip('\r')
    parts = val.split('\r')
    for part in parts:
        br = SubElement(val_node, 'br')
    return data

value = 'Hello\rworld\rI love you.'
print tostring(add_xml_data(value))
```

Comment: Could you give a sample input that should be transformed into the output you've posted? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, sorry. That is the output I'd like. The input would be a string
   'Hello\rworld\rI love you.'

Comment: can you give us a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) of what you've tried so far? i.e. what is the library you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). Here's the idea:

- replace `\r` with `<br/>` using string `replace()`
- place it inside the `<bar></bar>` tag using string formatting
- load the string using [`fromstring()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring)
- create `foo` element and [`append()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.append) the loaded tree to it

The code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

data = """
Hello\rworld\rI love you.
"""
data = '<bar>%s</bar>' % data.replace('\r', '<br/>')

bar = etree.fromstring(data)
foo = etree.Element('foo')
foo.append(bar)

print etree.tostring(foo)
```

It prints:

```
<foo><bar>
Hello<br />world<br />I love you.
</bar></foo>
```

Comment: I think this does it! Thanks. It is a different approach than I was using. May I ask why not use the SubElement(<node>, 'br')?
Cheer

Comment: @ToddMatsumoto I usually use it, but here the `bar` is loaded from string. Glad it helped.